# Cannot read files written using SXSSFWorkbook in java

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

I want to read and write large excel files. Therefore, I used SXSSFWorkbook to write the excel file and XSSF and SAX EVENT API to read the files.

However, the cell content is empty when the excel file is read, and if the excel file is written using SXSSFWOrkbook. If I open the written excel file and save it again, the content is shown correctly.

The following is the code I used to write the excel file.

```
    SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
    wb.setCompressTempFiles(true);

    SXSSFSheet sh = (SXSSFSheet) wb.createSheet();
    // sh.setRandomAccessWindowSize(100);// keep 100 rows in memory,
    // exceeding rows will be flushed to disk
    for (int rownum = 0; rownum < 100; rownum++) {
        Row row = sh.createRow(rownum);
        for (int cellnum = 0; cellnum < 10; cellnum++) {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum);
            String address = new CellReference(cell).formatAsString();
            cell.setCellValue(address);
        }

    }

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:\\tempsxssf.xlsx");
    wb.write(out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();        
    wb.dispose();
```

I am in a big trouble, can someone help me to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I used another constructor according [POI documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html#SXSSFWorkbook-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook-int-boolean-boolean-)

```
SXSSFWorkbook(workbook, rowAccessWindowSize, compressTmpFiles, useSharedStringsTable)
```

Like this:

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(null, 1000, true, true);
```

where you can enable shared strings table